# Cannot save keyframes / keyframes get overwritten?

Tags: animation, keyframes

TLDR: Keyframes get changed by other keyframes

Hey all,

I got an animation rig with some IK and bone parenting so both hands stay on the weapon. I have to correct the hand position on different frames because the location/rotation is not 100% correct. However after correction the location/rotation of another keyframe the other keyframes also change?! How is that possible when keyframing all bones? What do i have to do so keyframe 0 (and all other keyframes) are not affected by changing other keyframes?
Here some pictures:
Pose at keyframe 0:
[image]

Pose at  keyframe 4 (without correction):
[image]

After correcting the pose on keyframe 4:
[image]

Going back to keyframe 0:
[image]

Here my blend file:
[image]

Here is a short video where i replicate the problem and explain the behavior i want from blender:
https://youtu.be/AHzZIUuj69M

Please let me know if you need something else!

Comment: Hi Maffinius, there are several possibilities why this can happen. Unfortunately you didn't show us sufficient information/settings. So pls provide blend file so we can check it out. To name just one possible reason:  maybe you have autokeying switched on? And as we don't know - you see - we can just guess.

Comment: @Chris i added my blend file. I did not use autokeying :/

Comment: thx for the blend file. Now we only need to know which keyframes (name + values) did you change and which are then changing as well?

Comment: @Chris The problem exists for ALL frames i keyframed. In my last try i keyed all bones on frame 0 and 4 for example. But the problem also shows when editing other frames

Comment: how experienced r u with rigging? i am asking because i need to know what i can prerequisite or what i cannot prerequisite. If you move e.g. bone Wrist.R.001, which is ik target of Wrist.R, then of course by moving alone this bone, a lot of other bones will move and rotate as well. If you then keyframe all bones, it looks like a lot of bones change (which is actually true but that's the nature of ik)

Comment: so without trying to annoy you, pls tell us, what bone you change so we can tell you why other bones move as well. Thanks.

Comment: @Chris i move the Empty "leftHandHandle" (wich controls the position of the left hand IK aka. Wrist.L.001) and then rotate Wrist.L to match the rotation of the weapon. I have some minor experience with rigging. Ok i get that the bones influence each other with IK, but it is possible to set the exakt bone locations/rotation somehow (without changing other keyframes) right?
EDIT: Oh and pls do annoy me i want to learn! I feel like iam doing some pretty dumb mistake because setting a keyframe is like THE most basic thing to do in animation x)

Comment: keyframing might be easy, that's right - but rigging isn't ;) it's pretty complex. And if you don't wanna influence from the IK - you have to deactivate or delete it, but then you have to move every bone on your own. IK has the sense to make it easier to rig. But of course, IK does influence all bones which it is responsible of - even if you just move the one control bone (and that's how it should be). And if you then keyframe all bones, of course your whole animation looks different. If you want to match the weapon with the wrist, why don't you "bone parent" the weapon to your wrist?

Comment: @Chris yea i need the IK because setting every bone takes so much time and is not very accurate. I still dont get why the other keyframes get changed tho. In my mind keyframes just describe an absolute location/rotation/scale etc of a bone and the other values between get interpoliatet. Is there no way to keyframe/rig with IK? The right hand works perfectly with IK so why does the left not work even tho it uses the same IK?

Comment: maybe you can make a yt video and upload it what you are doing so we can see it? Would be great if you can speak out what you are doing and what you are expecting. I think that would make it much easier to understand what you did. Maybe it's just a simple thing i cannot think of....Of course you can keyframe a rig with ik. And yes, values get interpolated. But do you "just" keyframe the ik or all bones? as i said, before i ask many more questions, i think a video would help, you can put a link to it e.g. in your question or in the comments.

Comment: @Chris i added a short video :)

Comment: Vielen Dank! Das Video hat es sehr erleichtert zu verstehen, was du gemacht hast. Hättest du ja auch gleich sagen können, daß du deutsch verstehst ;) habe ein Antwort geschrieben. Der Grund ist, daß du das empty nicht gekeyframed hast. Das Empty ändert aber die bones wieder über copy location + IK. Du solltest also besser das empty keyframen, statt der bones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this "weird" behaviour is: you keyframed just the bones. But the empty (which control the bones via copy location) isn't keyframed by you. And this empty controls part of the bones and so the bones will be changed if you go back. So you should keyframe the empty instead - not the bones. Or maybe "all", so keyframe & bones to be sure. But this might be a bit of overkill.

Comment: I think i finally got it working! I followed your advice and keyframed the empty wich lead to another problem (setting the character model to another location) also described in this video: https://youtu.be/o5VJtVoUUhk . However i then tried to "Object ▸ Apply (Ctrl A) ▸ All Transforms" wich simply sets the empty to 0/0/0 with no rotation. So I reloaded the file and tried "Object ▸ Apply (Ctrl A) ▸ All Transforms to Deltas" and now it looks like it works how it should be. Thanks for your huge help! Marking this as resolved :)